# C++ conversion operator

Tags: c++

In following code:

```
if ( cin >> x ) { /* ... */ }
```

the standard library define an operator conversion *operator void**, which converts type *istream* to *void**. However, if the *if* tests a condition, why the standard library doesn't define a conversion from type *istream* to type *bool*? Or is there any implicit consideration behind the implementation?

Comment: New libraries (C++11) do. In older specs a direct conversion to `bool` was not used to avoid accidental implicit conversion to integral type (for ex: int)

Comment: _"because we need C in our C++ standard"_ I guess

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simple reason is that you don't want to accidentally end up with a conversion to an `int`. For example, assume there is an implicit conversion to `bool` and you wrote

```
if (std::cin << x) { /* ... */ }
```

The compiler couldn't catch the obvious error (using `<<` instead of `>>`) because the implicit conversion would convert to `int` and happily shift the result. That is almost certainly not what is intended. A `void*` can't be shifted, i.e., the compiler would yield an error instead.

Prior to C++11 there was no way to mark conversion operators `explicit`. You could only mark conversion constructors as `explicit`. In C++11 the conversion operator for streams was actually changed to an `explicit` conversion to `bool` as the conversion to `void*` had a few problems, too.

Comment: (+1) much better example and cleaner explanation then half written example I came up with.

Answer (score 3):

The `operator bool()` has always been a bit problematic. The main problem is that `bool` in C++ is an arithmetic operator, so any class that implements `operator bool()` will automatically be convertible to `int`.

Thus, the following code would be legal, but quite meaningless:

```
cout << (2 * cin);
```

The designers of the standard library thought that the operator less likely to cause problem, while at the same time being able to be converted to `bool` would be `operator void*`. The idea is that a `void*`, as is, cannot be used for anything.

That said, other more modern libraries, such as `boost` sometimes use the following idiom:

```
typedef void *this_type::*unspecified_bool_type;

operator unspecified_bool_type() const { return ... ; }
```

That is, instead of `bool` or `void*` they use a pointer-to-member-function, that will be truly useless other than being converted to `bool`.

That said, with C++11, the designers of the language noticed this problem and designed the following solution:

```
explicit operator bool() const
{ return ...; }
```

Now, this operator will only be called when the object is in a truly bool context (`if`, `while`...) , not in any random integral operation.